# Quickest Ways to Build Momentum?

Tags: wwe-13

What are some of the quickest ways to build momentum towards a signature move?  Do you have to vary your attacks or anything?  A series of strikes will build it up but it just seems to take forever compared to some videos I've seen of matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running strikes. Running grapples. varied attacks. quick grapple moves. don't repeat moves all the time. also reverse moves where you can. if you manage to knock down your opponent for a bit, taunt them.

If you really want to get in depth, the create-a-moveset option usually has the amount of momentum that each move delivers.

Regarding the videos, remember that some people do adjust their settings to make it suit them